# MERGE the edges even if the values differ?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, redisgraph

the following query will create (n1)->(n2) pair.
If the nodes already exists they will be reused.

```
   match (n1:X),(n2:X) where n1.val = 11 and n2.val = 12 
   merge (n1)-[x:q {val: 0 }]->(n2)
```

the problem is that if the edge with x.val that is different will create new connection.

Is there a way to disregard it ?

I want a single Query, which sets the value first time its called and afterwards ignore the value... OR I have to have two different queries one to set the pair and second w/o x.val that will just merge ?

---

this seem to work, but i would hear other possibilities :

```
        on create set x.val = 0.001
```

Answer (score 1):

`MERGE` has a `ON CREATE` clause that you can use :

```
MATCH (n1:X),(n2:X) WHERE n1.val = 11 and n2.val = 12 
MERGE (n1)-[x:q]->(n2)
ON CREATE SET x.val = 0
```